# Would it be acceptable to ask a question about pencil cases here?

Tags: discussion

There is a certain style of pencil case where I'm not sure what it's called, or where to find one because I got one for a present once, and I was wondering if it would be acceptable to be asked on this site, otherwise which site I should ask it on? This seemed to be the closest site for this topic, but I'm not sure if it completely matches the "theme" of this site...

Comment: LMAO This is probably the best question I've ever seen on Stack Exchange.

Comment: *goes to Stack Overflow....asks for help figuring out what brand of keyboard he once had...it had keys, was made of plastic...*

Answer (score 3):

Questions on "where to find Product X" are generally considered a poor fit for Stack Exchange sites - they're very limited in their usefulness, and the store selling them today might not be selling them in another couple of months.

As for identification - well, product-identification is not really our thing, and writing *tools and implements* are really borderline here... I would say that if by "what the style is called" you mean a certain *kind* of pencil case, easily distinguishable from other types, whose use and utility are somewhat different... then that's a question about tools, and I think we'd be OK with it. But if it's a particular design or visual style, then that's not really a writing issue, IMHO.

By means of analogy, I'd say "What kind of tool should I use for hitting things together?" would be OK, whereas "Where can I find a hammer with a red wooden handle?" would be too localized.

Thanks for checking for such a borderline case!

Comment: I understand...I was trying to find out more about a pencil case that I got a long time ago as a gift, and I have never seen anything like it, it has a trifold design with different things on each flap